# STM32 I2C reads additional "empty" byte

Tags: stm32, i2c

I am reading BMP180 pressure sensor on STM32 and well, it works, but, watching the transfer on the analyzer I can always see an extra empty byte read.

I am almost sure, it is because I give the I2C_GenerateSTOP() only after I I2C_ReceiveData() - this is kind of logical, but not as all the examples go. There, you call I2C_GenerateSTOP() even before waiting for the I2C_EVENT_MASTER_BYTE_RECEIVED of the last byte.

Now, if I do as the examples go, the readout is not stable: it works few times, then does not anymore: wait for I2C_EVENT_MASTER_MODE_SELECT after I2C_GenerateSTART() times out.

I tried to search various examples but was not able to find any clue how to resolve this.

Could anybody help ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the errata sheet for some of their chips describes this behavior

> **Description**
>   When the EV7, EV7_1, EV6_1, EV6_3, EV2, EV8, and EV3
>   events are not managed before the current byte is being transferred,
>   problems may be encountered such as receiving an  extra byte, reading
>   the same data twice or missing data.

Workaround is there too
http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/errata_sheet/CD00190234.pdf